# mysql replication with ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I'm working on a mysql replication with Ansible.

I have the following ansible task:

```
---
- name: update mysql config file
  template:
    src: templates/my.cnf.j2
    dest: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  notify:
    - restart mysql

- name: create replicator user
  mysql_user:
    name: "replicator"
    host: "%"
    password: "{{ mysql_replicator_password }}"
    priv: "*.*:REPLICATION SLAVE"
    state: present
  notify:
    - restart mysql

- name: Check replication init with checking file existence
  stat: path=/etc/mysql/repl.ansible
  register: check_sql_path

- mysql_replication:
    mode: changemaster
    master_host: "{{ groups.web[1] }}"
    master_user: replicator
    master_password: "{{ mysql_replicator_password }}"
  when: groups.web[1] is defined and check_sql_path.stat.exists == false and '{{ inventory_hostname }}' == '{{ groups.web[0] }}'
  notify:
    - restart mysql

- command: touch /etc/mysql/repl.ansible
  when: groups.web[1] is defined and check_sql_path.stat.exists == false and '{{ inventory_hostname }}' == '{{ groups.web[0] }}'

- mysql_replication:
    mode: changemaster
    master_host: "{{ groups.web[0] }}"
    master_user: replicator
    master_password: "{{ mysql_replicator_password }}"
  when: groups.web[1] is defined and check_sql_path.stat.exists == false and '{{ inventory_hostname }}' == '{{ groups.web[1] }}'
  notify:
    - restart mysql

- command: touch /etc/mysql/repl.ansible
  when: groups.web[1] is defined and check_sql_path.stat.exists == false and '{{ inventory_hostname }}' == '{{ groups.web[1] }}'
```

This tasks are ok when I ran it, but when i look with phpmyadmin the replication status I have the following message (on both server):

- Slave_IO_State:   Connecting to master
- Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
- Slave_SQL_Running: Yes

I'm not an expert in mysql replication, do you see anything can help me ?

(I follow this tutorial: https://raymii.org/s/articles/Building_HA_Clusters_With_Ansible_and_Openstack.html)

Thx

Comment: Why restart after granting privileges and change master?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not an expert in mysql replication, do you see anything can help me ?

It's 2 database servers running mysql in master-master replication:

> MySQL replication is the process by which a single data set, stored in
>   a MySQL database, will be live-copied to a second server. This
>   configuration, called "master-slave" replication.
>
> Master-master replication allows data to be copied from either server
>   to the other one. This subtle but important difference allows us to
>   perform mysql read or writes from either server. This configuration
>   adds redundancy and increases efficiency when dealing with accessing
>   the data.

Also your link describes that:

> We also use a double when conditional. We need to set up the servers
>   with each other's IP as the master. Therefore we need to run the setup
>   for host A with the master IP of host B, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
```

This sounds like you mysql server still listen on 127.0.0.1 (the default) and/or your firewall blocks connections.
Change bind-address config to 0.0.0.0 and it will connect.

But still, you'll have to get master position from groups.web[0] to configure groups.web[1] and vis et versa.